# Filter then sum dictionary with tuple as key

Tags: c#, dictionary, filter, tuples

I'm trying to filter and then sum a dictionary with a tuple as the key. There are a couple of [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131648/filtering-out-values-from-a-c-sharp-generic-dictionary) on SO, but nothing extensive. Any suggestions, please?

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, string, string, int, string>, double> dctMC = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, string, string, int, string>, double>();
List<int> listIDs = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5 };

// ID, TYPE, NAME, ORDER, COLOUR, WEIGHT
dctMC.Add(Tuple.Create(1, "Fruit", "Apple", 9, "Green"), 0.45);
dctMC.Add(Tuple.Create(2, "Fruit", "Grape", 5, "Red"), 0.78);
dctMC.Add(Tuple.Create(3, "Fruit", "Apple", 9, "Green"), 0.33);
dctMC.Add(Tuple.Create(4, "Fruit", "Peach", 2, "Yellow"), 0.89);
dctMC.Add(Tuple.Create(5, "Fruit", "Apple", 14, "Red"), 0.23);

// Sum dictionary where IDs in listIDs, Type = FRUIT, Name = APPLE, Order = 9, Colour = "Green"
double TOTAL = dctMC.Where(Z => listIDs.Contains(Z.Key(item1)) && 
                                Z.Key(item2) == "Apple" && 
                                Z.Key(item3) == 9 && 
                                Z.Key(item4) == "Green")
                    .Sum()
```

Comment: Good for adding the initializing code with the values - Makes it so much easier to understand the problem and help you solve it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is in the way you access the items in the tuple's key. They are properties of his.

*So if you try to put it into words it is kind of: `"Item in dictionary(KeyValuePair<>).Key.(Key is a tuple with 5 fields - so select property of that field)"`*

At the end - after finding the items that fit your request you get back an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>>` so when you `Sum` you should specify by what - in this case the `Value` of the pair.

```
double TOTAL = dctMC.Where(Z => listIDs.Contains(Z.Key.Item1) && 
                                Z.Key.Item2 == "Apple" && 
                                Z.Key.Item4 == 9 && 
                                Z.Key.Item5 == "Green")
                    .Sum(item => item.Value);
```

** Also notice that you accidently used `Item3 == 9` instead of `Item4` and same with `Item4 == "Green"` instead of `Item5`*

---

Don't know if this is for the sake of the question or not but I'd suggest to keep away from such `Tuples` and just put it in a proper defined class (or anonymous type if it comes from some other query)

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'm running a large simulation and I'm trying to analyze and store the results in a dictionary before adding them back to a datatable using a loop to access the key/value pair. If there is a better way of doing this please can you point me in the right direction? I decided to use a tuple instead of a nested dictionary.

Comment: is this a better way to handle layered data? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708236/c-sharp-nested-dictionary-better-alternative-best-organize-data-across-three-c)

Comment: @Zeus - Didn't look at it in details but if it is replacing the Tuple with 5 fields with a class - the answer is yes :)

Comment: thanks do you know of any links where I can learn how this is done? I have to use a layered structure or the class will have 5000 items...

Comment: 5000 properties? Then you have some design problem I think....... Just read in general about how to properly divide into classes and so. If you really have a class with 5000 fields.....Maybe use dynamic - but still I'd say there is a design problem..

Comment: sorry, 5000 variables, I can layer the dataset so the largest class has 21 properties

Comment: Hard for me to comment on this without knowing the bigger picture..... sorry... (but maybe if you get this data from a database then look into ORMs)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119002/discussion-between-zeus-and-gilad-green).

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate over a dictionary, the elements are `KeyValuePair<>` instances. You need to `Select` the values to sum them:

```
double TOTAL = dctMC.Where(Z => 
                       lstIDs.Contains(Z.Key.Item1)) && 
                       Z.Key.Item2 == "Apple" && 
                       Z.Key.Item4 == 9 && Z.Key.Item5 == "Green")
                   .Select(Z => Z.Value)
                   .Sum();
```

or use the `Sum()` overload with a selector lambda like this:

```
double TOTAL = dctMC.Where(Z => 
                       lstIDs.Contains(Z.Key.Item1)) && 
                       Z.Key.Item2 == "Apple" && 
                       Z.Key.Item4 == 9 && Z.Key.Item5 == "Green")
                   .Sum(Z => Z.Value);
```

Note that items in a `Tuple<>` are accessed like `tuple.Item1`, `tuple.Item2` etc, not `tuple(item1)`.

Comment: This won't compile - `Item3` is a string and `Item4` is int

Comment: @GiladGreen thx, must somehow have mixed up the indices while editing...

Comment: Not your mistake - It was an error in his original code :)

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to wrap your head around it if you break it into stages:
First filter out the non relevant items (by key), then sum the values:

```
var filtered =    //This is an IEnumerable of KeyValuePair<Tuple<int, string, string, int, string>, double>
    dctMC.Where(Z => listIDs.Contains(Z.Key.Item1) && 
                                        Z.Key.Item2 == "Apple" && 
                                        Z.Key.Item4 == 9 && 
                                        Z.Key.Item5 == "Green") 
var values   = filtered.Select(item => item.Value);  //the doubles you want to sum
double TOTAL = values.Sum();                         //The sum you were looking for...
```

Comment: thanks for all the help!!, I've got the code to work, but as per Gilad Green;s comment above there is probably a better method.